# P5JS - wrong canvas content scale

Tags: javascript, user-interface, canvas, p5.js

I'm making a snake game using P5JS. When I started creating the UI everything was fine until I tried to make a bar (life, progress). For displaying the state, I decided to copy a certain number of pixels to the rendered texture. First, to check how it will work, I created a function.

```
_cropOverlayTexture() {
    let width = this._overlayTexture.width;
    let height = this._overlayTexture.height;
    this._currentOverlayTexture = createImage(width, height);

    this._currentOverlayTexture.loadPixels();
    for(let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            this._currentOverlayTexture.set(i, j, [20, 250, 0, 255]);
        }
    }

    this._currentOverlayTexture.updatePixels();
}

update() {
    if(this._currentStep !== this._oldStep) {
        this._cropOverlayTexture();
        this._oldStep = this._currentStep;
    }
}

draw() {
    image(this._barTexture, this._x, this._y, this._width, this._height);
    image(this._currentOverlayTexture, this._x, this._y, this._width, this._height);
}
```

At this moment, the content inside the canvas has shifted relative to the x-axis. (Canvas has a size of 800 by 800)
[image: wrong scale and translate]

I removed this part of the code, but the defect is still there.
I tried changing the draw position and scale, but it has strange proportions, and the image also looks blurry.

```
function draw() {
    background(0);
    push();
    translate(0, 0);
    scale(0.375, 1);
    
    // draw UI
    
    pop();
}
```

[image: blurry image]

For comparison, this is how it looked before:

[image: correct image]

I tried to switch to WEBGL mode.

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(CANVAS_SIZE.X, CANVAS_SIZE.Y, WEBGL);
    // setup
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    push();
    translate(-400, -400);
    scale(1, 1);
    
    // draw UI
    
    pop();
}
```

But it did not help.

[image: scaled webgl]

I also tried clear browser cookies, restart IDE, computer, but nothing helped. What am I doing wrong and what could be the problem?

P.S: For example, I decided to remove all the code and leave the display of the square at 100 by 100 pixels.

```
function setup() {  
    createCanvas(800, 800);  
    frameRate(30);  
}  

function draw() {  
    background(0);  
    fill("#ff2574");  
    rect(100, 100, 100, 100);  
}
```

But the image still looks stretched.

Comment: There's insufficient code here to reproduce your issue. I've encountered blurry images in p5.js, but only when manually drawing to an image with the pixels array and not properly dealing with pixel density.

The code at the end definitely draws a perfectly normal pink square. If you're not seeing the pink shape as a square then my only guess that the canvas element is being distorted, by something like a css transform or browser zoom settings.

Comment: @PaulWheeler Unfortunately, I could not understand why this happened. I creating a new project and running this code, I got the normal square.
Then I created a new project and copied all the files from the game project, the defect appeared.
I created another new project, re-downloaded the P5JS library and transferred the contents of the files. It worked, now everything looks like it did before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to find the cause of this problem.

However, I solved the problem when I transferred the **contents** of the files from the project with an error to the new project and downloaded p5js library again.